# Best Latin translation of an English Phrase "Always Present, Never Seen"

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, meaning

I am designing some potential products for my organization, and I want to include a version that includes a tag line written in Latin of one of the our organizational values. The phrase I'm looking for a good translation for is:

> Always Present, Never Seen

It's okay to rearrange the words in the phrase to identify the best translation and maintain the same meaning from the English version of the phrase. I've tried using Google Translate and several other translators with MANY various results. If possible I'd also like to keep the final phrase as short as possible, similar to how the phrase is now.

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer!

Comment: Good call on checking this place. Google translate does not translate well.

Comment: Does this refer to a person, people, a thing or more than one thing?

Comment: It refers to an organization of people performing a service

Comment: Why would you want it in Latin? If you can’t translate it *into* Latin, I doubt many customers/members/whoever would be able to translate it *from* Latin—and if it’s incomprehensible, it kind of defeats the purpose, don’t you think?

Answer (score 8):

I would translate as follows. I put it in the plural form since it refers to an organization:

> Praesentes semper, numquam conspecti

There are a lot of words that have to do with seeing, but I chose the word [*conspecti*](http://%20to%20attract%20attention,%20to%20be%20conspicuous,%20noticed,%20observed,%20distinguished,%20admired) because the infinitive form has the meaning:

> to attract attention, to be conspicuous, noticed, observed,
>   distinguished, admired

Your team is always there to help, but without attracting attention.

Comment: what about "numquam vidistis" or "non vidistis"? I'm looking for something to describe the people or the work as being not seen and in the background... there but no one knows its going on

Comment: @DannyMorrison. I updated my answer.  The plural is in the participle as opposed to a verb form such as "vidistis", because "vidistis" refers to a the number of people seeing, and "conspecti" to the number of people seen.

Comment: @DannyMorrison *numquam vidistis* means "y'all never saw", while *non vidistis* means "y'all did not see".

Comment: I would use a chiasmus for a nice stylistic effect: *Praesentes semper, numquam conspecti* or the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

There is already an excellent answer, but perhaps a different suggestion might still be welcome?

You could also phrase it as **adsumus semper, numquam spectamur** — *we are always present, we are never observed*.

*adsum* has the connotation of being helpful, which might be a nice touch.